# Unable to remotely connect to a machine after succesfull VPN login

Tags: vpn, remote, mtu

I'm unable to remotely connect to a virtual machine even after successfully logging into VPN through my broadband connection. Weird it is, I'm able to remotely connect to that machine after VPN log in if I use Tata photon+ data card for internet connection. 
I'm facing the problem only if I use the broadband connection.
Any pointers please?

Thanks
Bharat

Comment: What kind of error you get? Any entries in the log on the virtual machine? DNS issues (if you access the VM by hostname and DNS is not passed through the VPN, i.e. if when going through the broadband connection you use that broadband ISP's DNS)?

Comment: @lupincho: This is the error I'm getting- "This computer can't connect to the remote computer. The two computers couldn't connect in the time allocated.". But sometimes it seems that it is getting connected to the VM. But all I'm able to see is a black screen. I'm trying to connect using the Remote Desktop connection utility in my windows xp machine and using the computer name "usvmxxxxxx".